# Thread: Not calling run method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new in java. Can someone help me why it is not calling Run method.
Thanks in advance.

```
package com.blt;

public class ThreadExample implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {       

        System.out.println("A");
        Thread T=new Thread();
        System.out.println("B");
        T.setName("Hello");
        System.out.println("C");
        T.start();
        System.out.println("D");
    }

public void run()
{
    System.out.println("Inside run");

}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of `ThreadExample` to the `Thread` constructor, to tell the new thread what to run:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadExample());
t.start();
```

(It's unfortunate that the `Thread` class has been poorly designed in various ways. It would be more helpful if it *didn't* have a `run()` method itself, but *did* force you to pass a `Runnable` into the constructor. Then you'd have found the problem at compile-time.)

Comment: I think in the very early days of Java there was a tendency to supply the run method by extending Thread, rather than passing a Runnable. That depended on Thread implementing Runnable, and therefore having a run method.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Absolutely - it was a bad idea then, too :) It's nice that best practice has moved on... it's a shame that we're stuck with badly-designed libraries forever...

Answer (score 2):

The `run` method is called by the JVM for you when a `Thread` is started. The default implementation simply does nothing. Your variable `T` is a normal `Thread`, without a `Runnable` 'target', so its `run` method is never called. You could either provide an instance of `ThreadExample` to the constructor of Thread or have `ThreadExample` *extend* `Thread`:

```
new ThreadExample().start();
// or
new Thread(new ThreadExample()).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way.Do not implement `Runnable` in your main class, but create an inner class within your `main` class to do so:

```
class TestRunnable implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Thread started");
   }
}
```

Instantiate it from your Main class inside the `main` method:

```
TestRunnable test = new TestRunnable(); 
Thread thread = new Thread(test);
thread.start();
```