# How method preference work in java?

Tags: java

I just want to understand how below code snippet work ?

```
class AnnaThread extends Thread {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread t = new AnnaThread();
        t.start();

    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Anna is here");
    }
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Rocky is here");
    }
}
```

Output - Rocky is here

Comment: check this out .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808895/thread-not-calling-run-method

Answer (score 3):

There's not much to explain.

- You override `start()` with code that prints `Rocky is here`
- then you call `start()` which prints `Rocky is here`.
- (the `run` method is never involved)

People often confuse the purpose of `start` and `run`. See for instance this question:

[Why we call Thread.start() method which in turns calls run method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052522/why-we-call-thread-start-method-which-in-turns-calls-run-method)

The rules are simple:

- `Thread.run` is an ordinary method (no magic)
- `Thread.start` contains some magic because it spawns a separate thread (and lets that thread invoke `run`).

  - If you override `Thread.start` with your own method, then there's no magic left anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

what you have here is a Java class which extends the Thread class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

`class AnnaThread extends Thread {`

then in your `main` method you create a `new instance` of the class which is a `Thread` (since the `class extends the Thread`)

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread t = new AnnaThread();
```

then you call the method start which follows bellow

```
        t.start();
```

which prints

`System.out.println("Rocky is here");`

you could as well call the other method if you add the following line in your code

```
      t.run();
```

in which case the method run would be executed which would print

```
        System.out.println("Anna is here");
```